# Handling functionality of wrapper classes

Tags: java, wrapper

Although the Wrapper classes provide needed functionality, Java code is sometimes overly complicated due to the necessary conversions between the primitive and wrapper versions of data being manipulated. How can this be handled?

Comment: Just be happy there is [autoboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)

Comment: Your question is unclear. What do you mean by handled?

Comment: Is this a homework question? If so, tag it as such.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Java, this is now handled automatically for you through a process known as [Autoboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html).

Autoboxing occurs when the code requires a reference type but you have passed a primitive type.  A common example is adding items to a collection.

```
LinkedList<Integer> myList=new LinkedList<Integer>();
int x = 3;
myList.add(x); //x is autoboxed from an int to an Integer.
```

Answer (score 1):

I know I put it in the comments section, but this after reading your question again. This is the exact reason they created autoboxing --> [Autoboxing](http://download.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/language/autoboxing.html)